# Advantage of avg_over_time(rate()) over rate() by itself?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Usually my queries with counter metrics look like this:

```
rate(metric_total[5m])
rate(metric_total[$__interval])
```

But while looking at various companies / teams using Prometheus and Grafana (for example the GitLab infrastructure team) I came across the following construct:

```
avg_over_time(recording_rule:rate_5m[$__interval])
```

So I would like to know: Is there an advantage to the second approach?

---

Here is a concrete example: https://dashboards.gitlab.com/d/frontend-main/frontend-overview?orgId=1&viewPanel=23

Comment: Dumb question perhaps, but how is $__interval at all similar to avg_over_time? When I change the interval, even to e.g. 10000m, it doesn't average or really change the output graph at all, it remains just as spiky as it was before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2nd approach doesn't require you to have recording rules for every possible interval over which you'd like an average rate, saving resources.

Comment: And I guess that goes well with your blog post I came across some time ago but had forgotten about *As with scrape and evaluation intervals it's best to have one standard range for sanity* [source](https://www.robustperception.io/what-range-should-i-use-with-rate)

Comment: That too, though that's more that you can't really do math between a 10m rate and a 5m rate - even eyeballing them is tricky.

Comment: @brian-brazil so using `rate` would go and somehow create multiple recording rules?

Answer (score 3):

The `avg_over_time(rate(metric_total[5m])[$__interval:])` calculates average of average rates. This isn't a good metric, since [average of averages doesn't equal to average](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect). So the better approach would be to calculate `rate(metric_total[$__interval])` - it returns the real average per-second increase rate for `metric_total` over the given lookbehind window `$__interval`.

Comment: As long as each of the inner averages covers the same number of data points, which will be true for the `rate`, then the average of averages taken here contains no Simpson's Paradox, so `avg_over_time` of a `rate` is acceptable here. In some circumstances like Sysdig's PromQL it's the only way to increase the range beyond the `$__interval` variable you are given.